# when-then-Return functions are not working

Tags: java, rest, junit, mockito

I am writing JUnit tests for a controller class. I have tried several methods, but the when.thenReturn() is getting bypassed every time. Following is the sample code:

Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class FundController {  
  @Autowired
  private FundDAO msDAO = new FundDAO();
  private FundUtil msUtil = new FundUtil();

    @PostMapping(value = "/v1/fund/search", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public FundSearchResponse fundNameSearch(
            @ApiParam(name = "fundName", value = "fund names in form of JSON", required = true) @RequestBody(required = true) fundName fundNameRequest,

            @ApiParam(name = "limit", value = "Number of Records per page", required = false, defaultValue = "10") @RequestParam(value = "limit", required = false, defaultValue = "10") Integer limit) {

        FundSearchResponse fundSearchResponse = new FundSearchResponse();

        if (!msUtil.validatefundSearchRequest(fundNameRequest, limit)) {
            String validationMsg = msUtil.getValidationMsg();
            fundSearchResponse.setResponse(
                    msUtil.buildServiceResponse(Constants.CODE_400_BAD_REQUEST, Constants.TYPE_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                            validationMsg.isEmpty() ? Constants.DESC_400_BAD_REQUEST : validationMsg));
            fundSearchResponse.setfunds(null);
            fundSearchResponse.setTotalRecords(0);
        }

        else {
            try {
                fundSearchResponse = msDAO.fundNameSearch(fundNameRequest.getfundName(), limit);
                if (fundSearchResponse.getfunds() != null) {
                    fundSearchResponse.setTotalRecords(fundSearchResponse.getfunds().size());
                    fundSearchResponse.setResponse(msUtil.buildServiceResponse(Constants.CODE_200_SUCCESS));
                } else {
                    fundSearchResponse.setTotalRecords(0);
                    fundSearchResponse.setResponse(msUtil.buildServiceResponse(Constants.CODE_200_SUCCESS,
                            Constants.TYPE_200_SUCCESS, Constants.DESC_404_NOT_FOUND));
                }
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                fundSearchResponse.setResponse(msUtil.buildServiceResponse(e.code, e.type, e.getMessage()));
                fundSearchResponse.setTotalRecords(0);
            }
        }
        return fundSearchResponse;
    }
```

JUnit test class:

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = FundController.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class FundTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
       
    @MockBean
    private FundDAO msDAO;

    private FundUtil msUtil;
    private fundName fundName;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() { 
        fundName = MockData.getfundName();
        msUtil = new FundsOrchestratorUtil();
        msDAO = new FundsOrchestratorDAO();
    }
    

    @Test
    public void shouldFetchAllUsers() throws Exception {

        fundsSearchResponse fundSearchResponse = MockData.getfundsSearchResponse();
        
        when(msUtil.validatefundSearchRequest(fundName, 5)).thenReturn(true);   // Problem : getting bypassed to Util class
        
        //given(msUtil.validatefundSearchRequest(Mockito.any(fundName.class), Mockito.anyInt())).willReturn(true);
        given(msDAO.fundNameSearch(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt())).willReturn(fundSearchResponse);

        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/v1/funds/search"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }  
}
```

I followed this web site [JUnit and Mockito](https://medium.com/backend-habit/integrate-junit-and-mockito-unit-testing-for-controller-layer-91bb4099c2a5), as my usual way of JUnit (`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`) were not working. Though both of these are almost same, the problem still persists. As the class call restriction using when().thenReturn() are not working. I am not good at JUnit, so I might be missing something. Please let me know how to get this done. As the dependent class is looking for the data in object which in this case is passed as Mockito.any(Classname.class). When passed with the object with data, its giving error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a mock first :

```
FundUtil fundUtilMock = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(FundUtil.class);
```

Then you can call :

```
when(fundUtilMock.validatefundSearchRequest(fundName, 5)).thenReturn(true);
```